# How to print PDF documents without highlights in Preview.app

Tags: pdf, preview, printing

I was trying to print a PDF document in which I highlighted some texts. In the printing preview, I saw those highlights, which I didn't really want for the printed document. I tried to disable the highlights but didn't find such an option, and ended up removing all the highlights before printing. So, does such an option (hiding highlights for printing) exist in Preview at all? Thanks.

By the way, I'm using Preview 7.0 (826) on OS X 10.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Preview.app there isn't an option, although there is a way:

> 1. Open your .pdf document
> 2. Select All (<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>)
> 3. Everything should be highlighted
> 4. <kbd>Control</kbd> mouse click on any page
> 5. From the popup menu > select the circle with a slash through it

[image]

> 6. Print your document
> 7. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo (re-enable highlights)

Answer (score 2):

There is a slightly complicated way that still works: go to the top menu *Tools* and open *Inspector*. A small window pops up, select the icon at the far right in the window ('Annotations Inspector').

In the list of all annotations select one and press command+a (select all) and then delete (backspace) to delete all annotations.

After printing (without closing the document in between!) you can get your annotations back through command+z (undo) - for this it should not matter if the inspector is selected or the main preview window.

I found the guide here in this five year old post here: https://protips.maxmasnick.com/preview-dot-app-remove-all-highlights-and-annotations-quickly

But it still works now (version 10.1).

Edit: Just found out - with this method you actually have to scroll down the document and repeat the deletion steps for every page.

Answer (score 1):

There no easy way to do this with Preview as of v8. You should [request the feature with Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html).

The best way to do this is to print the PDF with Acrobat instead. I'm testing with Acrobat Standard Pro v10.1. There, in the print dialog, you can can choose to print only the document or the document with markup.

[image: Print options to remove markup in Acrobat]

The solution by I'L'I will only remove highlights in Preview but not comments. Those will still be printed.